# extension of a continuous function

Tags: continuity

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map between two metric spaces. Can we extend $f$ to a function $f':X'\to Y'$ in such a way that $f'$ is also continuous ($X'$ and $Y'$ are also metric spaces), where $X$ and $Y$ are open subsets of $X'$ and $Y'$ respectively and the restriction of $f'$ in $X$ is $f$ and $(f')^{-1}(Y)=X$?

Comment: Sure just embed $X$ into $X'$ as a connected component and do the same for $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general.

Embed the real line $\mathbb{R}$ in the extended real line $\bar{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ in the usual way and also as $\mathbb{R}'=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\omega\}$ (the one point compactification).

Then the map $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ cannot be extended to a continuous map $f'\colon \mathbb{R}'\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Suppose there is no such f initially between X and Y but can we construct any f' between X' and Y' with the above condition?

Comment: @user155928 I can't understand

Comment: Suppose X and Y are two metric spaces.Can you find X' and Y' such that X and Y are open in X' and Y' respectively and there exist some f' such that f' inverse Y is X?

Comment: @user155928 Trivially take $X'=X$ and $Y'=Y$.

Comment: @user155928 Not in general. Take $Y$ a disconnected open subset of $Y'$ and $X$ a connected open subset of $X'$.

Answer (score 1):

As I currently understand your question, the answer is no.  For example, let $X' = \mathbb{R}, X = (0,\infty)$, and $Y = Y' = \mathbb{R}$.  The natural log is a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$ that has no extension to $X'$.

Maybe you can impose further restrictions on your question?